# regular expression to validate one semicolon in front of an email

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I need to match an instance of only one Semicolon in front of only one email address.
As below:

```
;myemail@somedomain.com
```

the regex should not match the following:

```
;myemail@somedomain.com;mysecondemail@somedomain.com
```

How do I match this pattern in regular expression?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: and what other data might you see here? because if it's just "an email, or an email with a ; in front of it" you can just blindly replace ';' with '' and not even bother with regexp at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regex like

```
^;\w+@\w+\.com$
```

see how the regex works at http://regex101.com/r/mW5qZ9/3

Comment: Just to be clear, that's not enough to validate an email address. This is not as easy a problem as it seems. http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @jzila the regex matches a very basic email. Op has not provided any conditions where it *must* and *must not* match

Comment: Not validating an email, simply validating the pattern with a presence of a semicolon in front of an email address, the email address will always be valid already(supposedly)

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to make sure that a comment existed with further reading in case OP needed greater robustness in his/her email validation regex.

Comment: @SariksaThapa in which case it would be prefrable you provide some examples on which the regex must match and not match. which could be helpful in forming the regex

Comment: @SariksaThapa but the regex won't match the second case

Comment: @nu11p01n73R that's exactly what I needed, for it to only match the presence of one semicolon in front of one email address. if there are two email addresses and the first email address starts out with a semicolon, that should be a no match. Your regex works great!

Comment: @jzila the writing a regex is entirely dependend on the form of data you need to match for matching a simple patterns as in question its not required to add complex character groups. simplicity is the beauty

Comment: @SariksaThapa glad to hear it helped. but if you want to match much more complex email addresses, you need to update the regex to include more details :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for positive lookahead: match a `;` followed by non-semicolons.

```
RegExp(/^;(?=[^;]+$)/).test(';')    // false
RegExp(/^;(?=[^;]+$)/).test(';x')   // true
RegExp(/^;(?=[^;]+$)/).test(';x;')  // false

RegExp(/^;(?=[^;]+$)/).test(';myemail@somedomain.com;mysecondemail@somedomain.com')
// -> false

RegExp(/^;(?=[^;]+$)/).test(';myemail@somedomain.com')
// -> true
```

If you want to match the starting semicolon *and* the email address after it (as you commented), then you don't need lookahead, just a regular match:

```
RegExp(/^;[^;]+$/).test(';myemail@somedomain.com;mysecondemail@somedomain.com')
// -> false

RegExp(/^;[^;]+$/).test(';myemail@somedomain.com')
// -> true
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only matches only the first semicolon, i want the expression to match the first semicolon and the first email following it. However it shouldn't match anything that  has more than one email addresses with a semicolon at the front like ;email@domain.com;email2@domain.com

Comment: @SariksaThapa in that case, I added another example for that